# Set `titleView` of `UINavigationItem` to view of a child `UIViewController` without adding to navigation stack

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController`, and I want to use its view as the titleView for a `UINavigationiten`. If the View Controller is a child of the top view controller, the app crashes when I set the `titleView`, since the parent should be the `UINavigationController` and not the top view controller. The issue is, if I make the View Controller containing the `titleView` a child of the Navigation Controller, the Navigation Controller teats the child as if it's a new item on the navigation stack (i.e. in a compact horizontal size class, it adds a back button to the navigation bar). How can I set the `titleView` to a view from a `UIViewController`, without it being added to the navigation stack?

Comment: A nav bar's `titleView` is for a small view with very little in it. Why do you need an entire view controller to create the view you wish to use as the `titleView`? What does this title view do that it needs its own view controller?

Comment: Is your goal to have a "persistent" `titleView` - with interactive elements - for all controllers in the navigation stack?

Comment: The goal is to have a `titleView` that's managed by a child of the Navigation Controller, without adding a new item to the navigation stack

Comment: @MichaelBerk - we need more details. What's in the `titleView` that it cannot be a `UIView` subclass?

Comment: @MichaelBerk A view can only have one superview. So you can't add the view controller's view as a subview of a parent view controller and also add it as a `titleView`.

Comment: I think the comments here are right - it's just easier to keep things simple and not have a separate UIViewController managing the title view